# how to find what information is being sent to a usb device by a software?

Tags: python, python-3.x, usb, libusb

I want to mimic the function that my keyboard's rgb software does using a piece of python code so I need to find what info the software sends to the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Event Viewer if you are using Windows 10.

Start Windows Event Viewer through the graphical user interface. Use the below steps to open Event Viewer on Windows:

- Open Event Viewer by clicking the Start button.
- Click Control Panel.
- Click System and Security.
- Click Administrative Tools.
- Click Event Viewer.

Comment: I checked out event viewer but can't figure out how to view the communication between the keyboard and the software.